# Jsoup.parse(String) - doesn't add \n

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup 1.7.2.

When using the API `Jsoup.parse(String)` I see that the output `Document` object adds line breaks (text line breaks, \n) in the parsed HTML.

For example:
The input string is:

```
<html><body><p>aaa</p></body></html>
```

And the `Document` object has the following (when calling the `toString()`):

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>aaa</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am interested in the `<body>` element. How to instruct Jsoup not to format the output with new lines? I am expecting the body part to be: `<body><p>aaa</p></body>`.

On the other hand when I have an HTML with line breaks, I want them to remain intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do this:

```
Document newDocument = Jsoup.parse(htmlString, StringUtils.EMPTY, Parser.htmlParser());
newDocument.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.base);
/**
 * Need CharEncoding.US_ASCII and not UTF-8 so the special characters will be encoded properly,
 * but representation of such will change. For instance: &mdash; will be encoded as &#8212;
 */
newDocument.outputSettings().charset(CharEncoding.US_ASCII);
newDocument.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false); // this will make sure that it will not add line breaks
```

Comment: thanks for this. Will it also save the line breaks if they were existed in original? (Updated my question)

Comment: @goryachev it will keep your original document exactly as it was prior parsing (with exception of special chars)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. Its working

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(String);
    // This line will keep your Html in one line
    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

    System.out.println(doc.html());
```